# UIDatePickerView date is always loading 0:01

Tags: ios, uidatepicker

I am trying to pass a time selected with a UIDatePicker to change a label's text, but when I update it, it always ends up as 0:01.

I have tried using the code on its own in a new project and it functions, so it's something about my other functions.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {    
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];
pickerLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
              [df stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]];
[self.view addSubview:pickerLabel];
[self.view addSubview:picker];    
}
```

and when the done button is clicked, it updates the label value and animated the uiview of the datepicker out.

```
- (IBAction)savePalette:(id)sender {

[UIView beginAnimations:@"animateView" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];

CGRect viewFrame = [animatedView frame];
viewFrame.origin.y = 480;
animatedView.frame = viewFrame;

animatedView.alpha = 1.0;
[self.view addSubview:animatedView];
[UIView commitAnimations];
NSLog(@"saving and close");

NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];
pickerLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [df stringFromDate:picker.date]];
NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[df stringFromDate:picker.date]]);
}
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks! The problem I think is that the date pulled from the picker is not transferred over.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How have you pulled the date selected from datepicker??
i. e you will have to specify how you have done this.  You speak about a done button- Is it used to select the date visible on picker without scrolling the Picker and selecting date??

I ran into a similar problem like you have and got it fixed by feeding a date into picker.

```
datePicker= [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:PICKER_FRAME;
[datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(selectedTime:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

Here the datePicker is loaded with default date which is [NSdate date].
Now try this;

```
NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];  
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];
    //Setting the locale causes dateformatter to format string in 12 hr format.
 NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
[dateFormatter setLocale:locale];
 NSString *dateString =[dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
 NSDate  *pickerLoadingDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
 datePicker.date = pickerLoadingDate;
```

Comment: I guess I don't know how to select the date from the done button. Ideally the done button closes the palette and pulls the date from the date picker. Is your second bit of code the selectedTime: method?

Comment: No the second bit of code is purely for datepicker initialisation.The method selectedTime is used to select the date picker date. This method will be called every time a datePicker receives a scroll and comes static with a date. So with a done button you will have to forcefully call the selectedTime method(within the selected time method you can get the date by datePicker.date).

Comment: UIBarButtonItem* doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done"
                                                                   style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self
                                                                  action:@selector(selectedTime:)] ;